# Make a check on a fictive column and return correct data

Tags: sql, oracle

Having this select:

```
  SELECT * (SELECT id, value, discount, 2 AS attr_number FROM database1 db1
      JOIN database2 db2 ON db2.db1_id = db1.id
    WHERE value = 1
    UNION
    SELECT id, value, discount, 1 AS attr_number FROM database1 db1
      JOIN database4 db4 ON db4.db1_id = db1.id
      AND db4.value = 1
    WHERE value = 1) WHERE id = 225
```

This is what im getting executing the select:

```
|ID           |VALUE                                  |DISCOUNT                               |ATTR_NUMBER                            |
|-------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|
|225          |1                                      |50                                     |2                                      |
|225          |1                                      |50                                     |2                                      |
|225          |1                                      |40                                     |1                                      |
|225          |1                                      |40                                     |1                                      |
|225          |1                                      |40                                     |1                                      |
```

I need to add check for `attr_number`column. If select has records where `attr_number = 1`, then the output should be like this(He should only return records where `attr_number = 1`):

```
|ID           |VALUE                                  |DISCOUNT                               |ATTR_NUMBER                            |
|-------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|
|225          |1                                      |40                                     |1                                      |
|225          |1                                      |40                                     |1                                      |
|225          |1                                      |40                                     |1                                      |
```

If select does not have any records where `attr_number = 1`, then he should return  records where `attr_number = 2`. Like this:

```
|ID           |VALUE                                  |DISCOUNT                               |ATTR_NUMBER                            |
|-------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|
|225          |1                                      |50                                     |2                                      |
|225          |1                                      |50                                     |2                                      |
```

The `attr_number` values can be only 1 or 2.

Comment: your question is unclear and contradictory, provide more details and example output of what you want to see

Comment: Rephrased. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing a `NOT EXISTS` clause:

```
WITH a1 as (
      SELECT id, value, discount, 2 AS attr_number
      FROM database1 db1 JOIN
           database2 db2
           ON db2.db1_id = db1.id
      WHERE id = 225 AND value = 1
    )
SELECT a1.*
FROM a1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, value, discount, 1 AS attr_number
FROM database1 db1 JOIN
      database4 db4
      ON db4.db1_id = db1.id
WHERE id = 225 AND
      db4.value = 1 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are looking for, but I think I am close enough:

```
SELECT * 
(
  SELECT id, value, discount, 1 AS attr_number 
  FROM database1 db1
  JOIN database4 db4 ON db4.db1_id = db1.id AND db4.value = 1
  WHERE db4.value = 1 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, value, discount, 2 AS attr_number 
  FROM database1 db1
  JOIN database2 db2 ON db2.db1_id = db1.id
  LEFT JOIN database4 db4 ON db4.db1_id = db1.id AND db4.value = 1
  WHERE db2.value = 1 and db4.value is NULL
) 
WHERE id = 225
```

Att#1 does not require any conditions as it gets the first priority. For Att#2, I have added another condition to verify if Att#1 has a value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your message. Att will be always 1 or 2, so there is no way that there could be any other value. Why should we check if values is null? We need to take in consideration only `attr_number` row.

Comment: If db4.value is NULL in the join statement, it means that Att#1 does not have any value...It's just another way of doing the not exists shown in the above answer